# Jolt : Keep all top-level fields, and put a particular sub-field to the top

Tags: json, jolt

I want to write a Jolt transformation that transforms this kind of JSON :

```
{
  "promoted_by": "client1",
  "parent": "parent1",
  "cmdb_ci": {
    "display_value": "cmdb_value",
    "link": "https://blabla"
  }
}
```

Into this :

```
{
  "promoted_by": "client1",
  "parent": "parent1",
  "cmdb_ci": "cmdb_value"
}
```

The real JSON contains way more fields. In other words, I want to keep all top-level fields, and when a field contains a "display_value" sub-field, it should take it and put it to the top-level, and discard other sub-fields like "link".

What I have now is something like this :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "display_value": "&1"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

The "display_value": "&1" part works to get put all display_value subfields to the top-level, but I don't know how to keep all other fields, without re-targeting everything with "*".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "cmdb_ci": { // else case
        "display_value": {
          "@": "&2" // @ : copies the value of "display_value" from one level up, &2 : copies the literal "cmdb_ci" by going two levels up the tree
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which respectively copies key vs. value from the top layers for the object with key `cmdb_ci`

or directly match the value of the identifier with one level upper key such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "cmdb_ci": {
        "@display_value": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Edit : You can convert the spec to the below one, considering that *you need to take into account all fields that have a display_value subfield, not specifically cmdb_ci as they are multiple similar fields which have both display_value and link subfields*

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@display_value": "&",
        "@": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "ONE"
    }
  }
]
```

which picks only the first matching component from the reformed array for the values of the top level object(namely `cmdb_ci` in this case)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to take into account all fields that have a display_value subfield, not specifically cmdb_ci as they are multiple similar fields which have both display_value and link subfields.

Comment: OK @asmoth I've edited based on your special case.

Comment: Thanks :)
I'm surprised a simpler solution doesn't exist, this seems quite complicated ! but it works so...